# Cant call JIBX CodeGen.

Tags: java, classpath, jibx

I want to create java classes from xml files. I use JIBX. I try this:

```
java -cp C:\Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои документы\Загрузки\jibx\lib\jibx-tools.jar org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen -t C:\Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои документы\Загрузки\jibx\gen\ -w C:\Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои документы\Загрузки\jibx\V01_STD\STD_MP.xsd
```

But get error

```
C:\Documents and Settings\kliver>java -cp C:\Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои д
окументы\Загрузки\jibx\lib\jibx-tools.jar org.jibx.schema.codegen.CodeGen -t C:\
Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои документы\Загрузки\jibx\gen\ -w C:\Documents a
nd Settings\kliver\Мои документы\Загрузки\jibx\V01_STD\STD_MP.xsd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: and.  Program will exit.
```

I add `C:\Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои документы\Загрузки\jibx\lib\` to PATH and CLASSPATH variables but its not help.

What i can foggot to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the word 'and' is interpreted as a java class. Try putting the paths refered to in the command line in quotes:

java -cp "C:\Documents and Settings\kliver\Мои д окументы\Загрузки\jibx\lib\jibx-tools.jar" .... etc

Comment: Thank for answer. But im find solution. Just download JiBX plugin for eclipse and its generate java classes automatically.